# Find Percent from List

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spyder

I have two lists that have been combined using zip, and I need to find the percent of one of these variables.

I have zipped these two lists so the proper values are associated. Next I need to single out one specific variable, give it a name, and find it's percent.

```
In: np.asarray((unique_elements, counts_elements))
Out: 
array([[     0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6],
       [ 84430,  23984, 107355,  91459,  80237, 179391,  69367]])
geologyzip = zip(unique_elements, counts_elements)

geologytotal=np.sum(geologyzip)
```

## I don't know if that last bit was correct, but I need to total these values and find the percent of #4 which I also need to associate with the name madison

I need something to say madison=x% but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Percent according to what value?

Comment: madison is associated with the #4 from the first list, so I used zip to combine those two lists to associate #4 with its value from the second list. I need to sum up the second list and find the percent of #4's value out of that sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can look at to see why numpy is a powerful source of one-liners.

```
import numpy as np
unique_elements, counts_elements = np.array([[     0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6],
                                         [ 84430,  23984, 107355,  91459,  80237, 179391,  69367]])  


value = 4
percent = counts_elements[unique_elements==value].sum()/counts_elements.sum()*100.0
```

This says sum all elements in `counts_elements` corresponding to `unique_elements` being equal to the `value` you specify, then divide it by the total count `counts_elements.sum()`. This is slightly overkill. You could study it to figure out why.